# Show annotation view after load map(not after click)

Tags: iphone, ipad, mapkit, mkannotation

I want show annotation view (above one of my pin) after load map. For example in viewDidLoad.

How i can show it in code and don' t destroy possibility of click it(to show/hide) how it always works. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, don't use `viewDidLoad`, use the mapView delegate `mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap`

Then in `mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap` use the `selectAnnotation:animated:` method to show the callout for your annotation.

See [MKMapView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html) for more information